# Recommendation on stochastic process books

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I was wondering if someone could recommend good books on stochastic processes

- with measure theory treatment
- with not much or no measure theory
  treatment

for each, it would be nice to have some books for introductory level, mid-level to comprehensive level respectively. They can be either classical or recently published, either continuous, discrete or both.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a mathematician it feels really horrible (to me) to do it in a non-measure theoretic sense, things get much more messy and less rigorous then.

Comment: @Jonas T: one can just contribute to those with measure theory treatments. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Teuwen , is it possible to after basic probability & statistics course, go directly to the measure theory firstly and then to the stochastic processes ? Because I'm bachelor student in applied maths in Sweden, in our program, stochastic processes is not obligatory, another elective option is mathematical modelling 2. I'm not sure whether it's better to learn "measure" based stochastic process on my own directly.

Comment: @Xingdong: Hi. I think it is possible if you have also done a course in real analysis. Depending on how "mathematically mature" you are it can be quite easy to learn the basics.

Answer (score 10):

Some good books include:

- *Stochastic Processes* by Sheldon Ross (no measure theory)
- *Introduction to Probability Models* by Sheldon Ross (no measure theory)
- *Stochastic Processes* by J.L.Doob (measure theory)

Comment: The Sheldon Ross book can not really be recommended. For instance, if I'm not mistaken, it uses conditional expectation before it defines it. Now, either it is supposed to be an introduction, in which case this is just horrible (or not, in which case I don't understand why it dwells on these simple things at length, and it doesn't read at all like it is meant for people who already know these things).